# Simple way to prompt user to authenticate when accessing Swagger UI (Web API 2)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, swagger-ui

I'm using Swagger to document my services (Web API 2). I'm looking for a real lightweight approach to requiring the visitor to enter a username / password before they can access the UI interface.

This result is exactly what I'm trying to achieve: 
[Example of API authentication prompt](http://www.icabbi.com/api/html/index.html)

It is only the Swagger UI that I wish to password protect and not the actual services.

I've tried authorization rules in web.config but couldn't get this to work (perhaps because the UI folder doesn't physically exist). I've also had a look at URL Authorization and Basic Authentication but I'm not really making progress.

I'm after the end result as per the image below:

[image: Authentication Prompt]

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: --Authorization via `web.config` in `<location path="PATH">..</location>` should work fine also with the dynamic routing. Can you please provide the web config sample, which doesn't work.-- Sorry, it seems indeed it doesn't work for dynamic paths

Answer (score 0):

I had a re-think about this and decided there was a more sensible solution that was also better practice.

I created a new version under a 'test' sub domain (e.g. test.api.mydomain.com) and used IIS Basic Authentication to protect the entire directory (obviously ensuring the user has minimal rights and a strong password).

For the production code I then disabled Swagger by removing the "EnableSwaggerUi" call in the SwaggerConfig.cs file.

This allows me to open up a test area for partners that is password protected and removes the need to password protect Swagger in production.